# SQL query for join table

Tags: sql, select

Table : **service_providers**

```
 id   name
 -----------
   1   A
   2   B
   3   C
   4   D
```

Table **service_providers** mapping

```
id   service_receiver_id    service_provider_id
---------------------------------------------------
 1            1                      2
 2            4                      1
```

How can I write a SQL query to retrieve `service_provider_id = 1`, associated with in the above mapping table?

I need the results like this:

```
id    associated_with
---------------------
 1          2
 1          4
```

Comment: can you explain what you want, it's not clear which table you want to join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your results seem to come from the second table, so you don't even need a join:

```
SELECT service_receiver_id AS associated_with
FROM   mytable
WHERE  service_provider_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT service_provider_id AS associated_with
FROM   mytable
WHERE  service_receiver_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
       WHEN r.service_provider_id <> 1 THEN r.service_provider_id
       ELSE r.service_reciever_id
    END as associated_with
FROM
    Relationships r
WHERE
    r.service_provider_id = 1
    OR r.service_reciever_id = 1
```

@Mureinik is correct you don't need the join, but to offer another solution that doesn't require union you can always use a case statement and OR in the where clause as well.

Could the service provider also be a receiver ever?  Or if duplicate records exist you might want to consider DISTINCT to eliminate if possible.